# Single quotes in JSON from PHP causing problems

Tags: php, jquery, json, cross-domain, str-replace

***NOTE:*** this was a completely different question until I realized where the problem really was.

My current issue is that I am trying to output some JSON from PHP for use by jQuery.  I am doing this cross-domain so I am using "JSONP".  I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that there are single quotes in my JSON so when I output with the callback function I end up getting too many single quotes.
I have tried calling `str_replace("'","\'",$value)` in PHP and it seems to output as `\\'` in my JSON rather than `\'` which is apparently not readable by jQuery (though online JSON validators say the JSON is valid.

So what I need to know is how to get only a single slash in my string inside of PHP rather than 2 slashes.

Comment: See my answer below. Also, re:**EDIT2**, use `"\\'"`. A single quote doesn't require escaping within double quotes, however the backslash does. (just escaping the wrong character)

Answer (score 1):

What I'm gathering is this:

jQuery uses `_` as a callback parameter to JSONP requests.  It will automatically append `?_=jQuery<random_numbers>` basically telling the server to call this unique function name when it returns. As such, as of recently (within the last year I want to say) `.ajax` takes care of making a callback function for you, then kind of "re-routes" it to a function you specify within the `success` property.

Also, your PHP code is using `$_GET['callback']` when it now should be using `$_GET['_']` (to stay more in-line with jQuery and what it's sending).

The "jQuery was not called" is just jQuery notifying you that anticipated callback wasn't included in the response, and it was looking to make sure it was getting called.

Short answer (as I see it) reference `$_GET['_']` instead of `$_GET['callback']` to satisfy jQuery.

Comment: You may be right about the '_' vs 'callback' but that isn't my problem.  Like I said, this exact setup works perfectly for a different button returning different JSON.  The problem is the single quotes in my JSON, so I should probably ask a completely different question since it is now about outputting JSON via PHP.  Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in your PHP:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($your_array_data) . ')';
```

Regards.